# How to go about detecting data usage in the Android environment

Tags: android

I would like to be able to detect all forms of data usage using the Android environment. Is it possible to keep tabs on which applications call on say [RTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol) vs [WAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Application_Protocol), etc. such that I can know at all times when data is being used by a native program or third-party app?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are talking about an Android API to monitor network statistics by application then such an API seems to have been added in [Android 2.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Froyo) (Froyo).

The main class you'll need is *[TrafficStats](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html)*.

You can use `getUid{Rx|Tx}Bytes(int uid)` for the given process user ID (which you can get from `ActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses()`).

The API is very simple and simply gives you the total bytes received/sent, so you'll have to do some more work to keep track of hourly, daily, and monthly stats. Well, that all depends on your needs.

I haven't tried using it myself, so I cannot give you any more detail, nor do I know the supported devices (not all devices will support this as the API points out).

Comment: hmm that does give me some direction. I appreciate it. But you said I can't use this for earlier versions? and there is no way to addrss this for earlier versions? just curious?

Comment: can I get the RX/TX stats from ADB? or is the only way to access them is through an app. I would like to know if I could do something like ADB Shell cat proc/int_UID/net/dev > C:\netstats.txt ... but actually get the rx/tx stats from individual applications

Comment: Not working on device below JELLY_BEAN_MR2.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html#getUidRxBytes(int)