# Data Transfer Rate

Tags: android

Hi guys I am developing an app to display data rate on status bar like this.[image]

My code is :

```
private class DataStatUtil implements Runnable {

        private long startRX = 0;
        private long lastRx = 0;
        private Handler mHandler;
        private Context context;
        private Intent actionIntent;


        public DataStatUtil(Context context ,Handler handler) {
            this.context = context;
            mHandler = handler;
            startRX = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            long rxBytes = (TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()- startRX)/1024;
            startRX = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();

            //my method to display on status bar
            notifyOnStatusBar(rxBytes);

            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);

        }
    }

}
```

I am asking is this is the right way?

Answer (score 0):

You should find Transmitted bytes also to get the total bandwidth usage in your connection. A/C to the above given code, you are monitoring only the total receiving bytes.

check this link to get more information.

[How do I programmatically show data usage of all applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674790/how-to-programatically-show-data-usage-of-all-applications?lq=1)

Comment: Thanks for the replay. But I am only concern about receiving rate.