# How to get Data usage for last 1 month in android?

Tags: android, android-data-usage

I need to get data usage statistics for last month.

Is there any way to calculate data usage date wise in android?

I used **TrafficStats** class for getting data usage but it gives me all data usage of device by the given UID since device boot.

Comment: You should also follow this link[it will help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674790/how-to-programatically-show-data-usage-of-all-applications)

Comment: are you found any solution? if yes,please help me i also stuck on the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

for those who are still looking, put this in onCreate.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    installedTime = getInstalledTime();
    if (checkUserStatePermission()) {
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS), REQUEST_USAGE_PERMISSION);

    } else {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                
       ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
                    }, REQUEST_PHONE_STATE);
        }
        else getInternetUsage();
    }
}
```

then these methods in your activity,
**IMPORTANT** in this case installedTime is the start time of month (long)

```
private void getInternetUsage() {
    NetworkStatsManager networkStatsManager = (NetworkStatsManager) getSystemService(Context.NETWORK_STATS_SERVICE);
    NetworkStats.Bucket bucketWifi, bucketMobile;

    try {

        bucketWifi = networkStatsManager.querySummaryForDevice(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI,
                "",
                installedTime,
                System.currentTimeMillis());

        bucketMobile = networkStatsManager.querySummaryForDevice(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE,
                getSubscriberId(),
                installedTime,
                System.currentTimeMillis());


        Log.d("MOBILE INTERNET UP", bucketMobile.getTxBytes() / (1024f * 1024f) + " MB");
        Log.d("MOBILE INTERNET DOWN", bucketMobile.getRxBytes() / (1024f * 1024f) + " MB");


        Log.d("WIFI INTERNET UP", bucketWifi.getTxBytes() / (1024f * 1024f) + " MB");
        Log.d("WIFI INTERNET DOWN", bucketWifi.getRxBytes() / (1024f * 1024f) + " MB");


    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


/*
we can pass null above Q
 */
@SuppressLint({"MissingPermission", "HardwareIds"})
public String getSubscriberId() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        return telephonyManager.getSubscriberId();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
private boolean checkUserStatePermission() {
    AppOpsManager appOps = (AppOpsManager)
            getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
    int mode = appOps.checkOpNoThrow("android:get_usage_stats",
            android.os.Process.myUid(), getPackageName());
    return mode != AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_USAGE_PERMISSION) {
        if (checkUserStatePermission()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        } else {
            getInternetUsage();
        }

    }
}
```

PS: I just edited my code as per this requirement so it may have some syntext error