# Get to know the last activity time of a service

Tags: android, service

I am trying to find the last activity time of a running service on an android device.I have tried the following.

```
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) 
{
if (service.service.getClassName().contains("com.truecaller"))//for example
{
    System.out.println(service.service.getClassName());

    System.out.println(service.lastActivityTime);

    System.out.println(service.activeSince);
}
}
```

I put a tag for system.out on logcat.i executed the program twice with a gap of a minute between the executions.But the output was exactly the same for both.how is that possible.how do we find the actual last activity time of a service?any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What kind of activity do you wish to detect?

Comment: anything..which is prone to be active

Comment: That's not really descriptive.. your deleted explanation was more so.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: How can i find the Data Usage on Per Application Basis?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939939/android-how-can-i-find-the-data-usage-on-per-application-basis)

Comment: hey sorry this is not what i wanted.for example i catch whatsapp's servive.i execute it once..tell my friend to send me a message on whatsapp.then execute again..Then the last activity time must have changed right?but its not happening

Comment: You can track the internet activity of WhatsApp or other apps using the solutions provided in that post.

Comment: learnt many things because of your reply.Thanks a bunch:)

Answer (score 1):

> But the output was exactly the same for both.how is that possible.

Quoting [the documentation for `lastActivityTime`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo.html#lastActivityTime):

> The time when there was last activity in the service (either explicit requests to start it or clients binding to it).

Presumably, in that minute, nobody called `startService()` or `bindService()` for this service.

Quoting [the documentation for `activeSince`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo.html#activeSince):

> The time when the service was first made active, either by someone starting or binding to it.

Therefore, this will only change if the service was stopped and then started (via `stopService()` or `stopSelf()`) or the process was terminated.

Hence, off the cuff, your results would seem to match the documented behavior.

> how do we find the actual last activity time of a service?

I do not know what "last activity time" means with respect to a service.

Comment: Thanks for your time.u are probably right about the activeSince part of the  question.But i got some doubts about the lastActivityTime part.for example i catch whatsapp's servive.i execute it once..tell my friend to send me a message on whatsapp.then execute again..Then the last activity time must have changed right?but its not happening

Comment: @user3837789: "Then the last activity time must have changed right?" -- not necessarily. It would depend upon how Whatsapp is written.