# Android: Getting Application Runtime Metrics

Tags: android, performance-testing

I have a Application which is hitting many Services through Asynctask. I want to calculate the amount of Memory + Bandwidth + Excecution Time based while sending the request and while parsing the response on Runtime in the device.

As far i could find few commands like **dumpsys meminfo, top** and few others, but in that which is the exact command to get my desired result as these commands give us a lot of information.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several questions addressing all of these issues right here on SO, so I am not sure what you are missing. For example [How can I find the data usage on a per-application basis on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939939/android-how-can-i-find-the-data-usage-on-per-application-basis)

To get memory usage for a given pid, use the ActivityManagers dedicated methods for this. I am not sure what you mean by getting the amount of "memory while sending the requests" though. The peak RAM usage of each request seems hard to define.
For execution time, I would just create my own timestamp probes.

Comment: "memory while sending the requests" 

I mean the memory Usage as i am using Hashmap for creating the Request body and headers.

"There are several questions addressing all of these issues right here on SO"

I could get the commands as "top" , "meminfo" etc., but it will give me many details, in that i need to know the exact parameter which gives me the needed info.