# how to get mobile data usage from the android device?

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, usage-statistics, mobile-data, android-data-usage

Does anyone know, how can I get mobile data usage from the android device? I've tried this code, but It only returns data for the current month - but I need this statistics for longer time(not only the current month)

```
long mobile = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
Log.d(TAG, "mobile internet: " + mobile / 1024 + " Kb");
```

Is there a way to get this using `getContentResolver().query` like we do for getting calls or sms history?

Just to clarify I am looking for the data from this screen:
[image]

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/create-a-network-monitor-using-androids-trafficstats-class/

Comment: @Darko did you saw this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939939/android-how-can-i-find-the-data-usage-on-a-per-application-basis