# DataUsage by a single API/webservice call

Tags: android, usage-statistics

I need to find how much data is consumed by single webservice/API call. I have searched a lot and found this:

[commonsguy/cw-andtuning](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-andtuning/tree/master/TrafficMonitor)
[How can I find the data usage on a per-application basis on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939939/how-can-i-find-the-data-usage-on-a-per-application-basis-on-android/11940219#11940219)

But these gives me DataUsage of whole application, i want to find it for single API/webservice call.

Answer (score 0):

THere is no built in way to do that.  You'd need to do it yourself, by adding the size of the data returned each time you call it.

Answer (score 0):

If you execute one API call at the time, then you might look into `android.net.TrafficStats`. Inside it, there is a method `android.net.TrafficStats#getUidTxPackets(int uid)` and `android.net.TrafficStats#getUidRxPackets(int uid)`. You might obtain your application uid from `android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo#uid`.

Get the value before a call, then get it once again after a call, and count the difference.

However, be advised:

> Before android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES#JELLY_BEAN_MR2, this may return UNSUPPORTED