# Android : Is there anyway to monitor network usage without root?

Tags: android

I am trying to collect network usage for each application/process. I've tried to read `/proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats` from my application, but I found it can only read its own line, not all data.

I wonder if there is a way to get what I need?

Comment: You might want to look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939939/how-can-i-find-the-data-usage-on-a-per-application-basis-on-android).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find the data usage on a per-application basis on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939939/how-can-i-find-the-data-usage-on-a-per-application-basis-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) to create a proxy, then you can setup that proxy on your device and finally see everything you want from Charles' client.

Regards!