# Fetch usage of other apps from my application in Device Admin mode

Tags: android, device-admin

I have an Android app for which I wanted in **COSU** mode. I have successfully **activated my device into Device Administrator mode**. 
Now I want the **data of the usage of other apps used daily**. For eg: Facebook, etc. I need the data to monitor usage of other apps. How can I achieve this programmatically?
TIA.

Comment: by logs are you refering to logCat ?!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692103/read-logcat-programmatically-within-application

Comment: @AmirHosseinMirzaei - No, I want the data. I saw the confusion, hence I have edited the question. I want the data of other apps that are being used in that device.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what you are looking for, but do you mean something like `UsageStatsManager` 
([documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager))?

Answer (score 0):

Using Android library class [TrafficStats](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats), you can find how much bytes received/sent across mobile networks since the last boot.

Also, you can find how much of bytes transmitted/received by the given UID since device boot. and you can find any package UID with `RunningAppProcessInfo`.

Here is a detailed answer on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11939939/4825703) and an [article](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/create-a-network-monitor-using-androids-trafficstats-class/) on Creating a network monitor