# How to get data usage for specific application for Android projects

Tags: android

getting usage for network in my application. How much spent network usage for Android project. Thank

Comment: I don;t think it's possible. You will have to manually calculate it with each request

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find the data usage on a per-application basis on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939939/how-can-i-find-the-data-usage-on-a-per-application-basis-on-android)

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko some application from playstrore . That are getting data usage from specific app installed application.

Comment: @theJango i will check it this. Thank :)