# How to get data(mobile and wifi) usage of each application in android?

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-data-usage

How to get data `(mobile and wifi)` usage of each application in android?

> Hello guys,
>   I want to know that how much data `(mobile and wifi)` used by each application. Actually I need a solution which gives data usage of applications in a given time period i.e. in each month.
>   Is there any possible way for find mobile and `wifi` usage of each application in android? 
>  like this image :

[image]

I am searched many links,posts on `Stackoverflow` and tried to search API for usage data in Android but still not success. I need some demo code or demo.

Can anybody help me please? Thanks...

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/11940219/7352857 @Haresh Solanki.

Comment: Hello dear, i try but its not work.