# How to measure mobile data traffic on Android

Tags: android, traffic-measurement

I'm developing an application that measure the data traffic recived through mobile data interface (no wifi) from all processes. Additionally this counter have to be related to a date range, i.e. betheen March 1 and April 1.

I had read about TrafficStats class, but in the documentation doesn't mentioned any about from when are the stats.

This is my first question and I really appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812032/how-to-go-about-detecting-data-usage-in-the-android-env. Should give you an insight of how to do it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939939/android-how-can-i-find-the-data-usage-on-per-application-basis. One more for your reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I had read about TrafficStats class, but in the documentation doesn't mentioned any about from when are the stats.

"From when" should not matter to you. Take a reading at a point in time, take another reading at a later point in time, and the difference between the two is the bandwidth consumed between those two points in time.

> Additionally this counter have to be related to a date range, i.e. betheen March 1 and April 1.

You would need to handle this yourself, most likely, checking for the amount of bandwidth consumption every so often (e.g., every 4 hours via `AlarmManager`), storing the results in a database, and then using that information to determine the bandwidth consumed over extended periods of time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I solved the problem based on you told me.

Comment: i have the same issue,,,can you shares some code snippets ?

Comment: @dinostroza   can you shares some code snippets pls